# smart pointer the element of a std::pair

Tags: c++, c++11, smart-pointers

I have a function which return a `std::pair<objectA*, objectB*>`. The documentation of the function says that it is my responsibility to deallocate the two elements. Now I am simply doing:

```
{
  std::pair<objectA*, objectB*> the_pair;

  ...

  if (condition) {
     delete the_pair.first;
     delete the_pair.second;
     return;
  }

  ...

  delete the_pair.first;
  delete the_pair.second;
}
```

how can I use smart pointer to automate the deletion of the two elements when `the_pair` goes out of scope?

Comment: `std::pair<std::unique_ptr<objectA>, std::unique_ptr<objectB>>`

Comment: @TheOne I think you misread the question slightly.

Comment: yea, seems like it, but the question is not really all that clear either

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If I understand correctly, it is the responsibility of the caller to delete the pointers. In that case, you could create a unique_ptr managing each element of the pair:

```
{ // some scope

  std::pair<objectA*, objectB*> the_pair = the_function();
  std::unique_ptr<objectA> pfirst(the_pair.first);
  std::unique_ptr<objectB> psecond(the_pair.second);

} // pointers get deleted
```

Alternatively, you can write your own scope guard:

```
struct pointer_pair_guard
{
  pointer_pair_guard(std::pair<objectA*, objectB*>& p) : p_(p) {}
  ~pointer_pair_guard() 
  { 
    delete p_.first;
    delete p_.second;
  }
  pointer_pair_guard(const pointer_pair_guard&) = delete;
  pointer_pair_guard& operator=(const pointer_pair_guard&) = delete;
  private:
    std::pair<objectA*, objectB*>& p_;
};
```

then

```
{ // some scope

  std::pair<objectA*, objectB*> the_pair = the_function();
  pointer_pair_guard gd(the_pair);

} // pointers get deleted
```

Comment: +1 like it, particularly because if the library vendor ever changes their memory policy, you just need to adjust the guard class.

Comment: What is `(_p)`? Do you mean `p_(p)`? I get: `anachronistic old-style base class initializer`

Comment: @RuggeroTurra That was a typo. Should have been `p_(p)`.

Comment: The other advantage of the guard is that you can give the two values more significant names than `first` and `second`.  (Using `std::pair` is almost an anti-pattern, except in the rare cases where `first` and `second` are the appropriate names.)

Answer (score 8):

I'd be tempted to *stub* the function and use the stub.

```
std::pair<
    std::shared_ptr<objectA>,
    std::shared_ptr<objectB>
> nice_foo(...)
{
    std::pair<objectA*, objectB*> temp = bad_foo(...);    
    return std::pair<
        std::shared_ptr<objectA>,
        std::shared_ptr<objectB>
    >(std::shared_ptr<objectA>(temp.first), std::shared_ptr<objectB>(temp.second));
}
```

In your code, instead of calling `bad_foo`, call `nice_foo`. The returned pair owns the memory so you don't need to worry about deleting it.

Comment: Not as cute as @juanchopanza's solution since you have to duplicate the function parameter list: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself

Comment: +1 anyway; you're not repeating yourself, you're repeating somebody else :-)

Comment: @Bathsheba I think this is ok for a one-off use for a library function.

Answer (score 7):

A `std::pair<std::unique_ptr<A>,std::unique_ptr<B>>` is the obvious solution.  But we want it to be clean at the point of use.  So:

```
template<class...Ts, template<class...>class tup, class... Us, size_t...Is>
tup<Ts...> tuple_cast(std::index_sequence<Is...>,tup<Us...>&&u){
  return tup<Ts...>{static_cast<Ts>(std::get<Is>(std::move(u)))...};
}
template<class...Ts, template<class...>class tup, class... Us, size_t...Is>
tup<Ts...> tuple_cast(std::index_sequence<Is...>,tup<Us...>const&u){
  return tup<Ts...>(static_cast<Ts>(std::get<Is>(u))...);
}
template<class...Ts, template<class...>class tup, class... Us>
tup<Ts...> tuple_cast(tup<Us...>&&u){
  static_assert( sizeof...(Ts)==sizeof...(Us), "must map one type to one type" );
  return tuple_cast<Ts...>(std::index_sequence_for<Us...>{}, std::move(u));
}
template<class...Ts, template<class...>class Tup, class... Us>
Tup<Ts...> tuple_cast(Tup<Us...>const&u){
  static_assert( sizeof...(Ts)==sizeof...(Us), "must map one type to one type" );
  return tuple_cast<Ts...>(std::index_sequence_for<Us...>{}, u);
}
```

now `auto x = tuple_cast<std::unique_ptr<A>,std::unique_ptr<B>>( func() )` is a way to turn the pair of pointers to a pair of unique pointers.

We can do better.

```
template<class A>
struct as_unique{using type=A;};
template<class A>
struct as_unique<A*>{using type=std::unique_ptr<A>;};
template<class A>
using as_unique_t=typename as_unique<A>::type;

template<class...Ts, template<class...>class tup>
tup<as_unique_t<Ts>...> take_ownership(tup<Ts...>&& t){
  return tuple_cast<as_unique_t<Ts>...>(std::move(t));
}
```

and if the typos are fixed, we get:

```
auto p = take_ownership( func() );
```

which looks cleaner at point of use.<sup>2</sup>  This takes any pointer values `T*` in your `std::pair` or `std::tuple`, converts them to `std::unique_ptr<T>`s, generates the corresponding type for output, then casts each field using `static_cast` to make the conversion explicit.

[live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/892480c54d5a3c80)

The above uses C++14 index sequences.  They can be written in C++11 in a dozen lines or so, so I don't feel bad about it.

Comment: `take_ownersip` passes an lvalue to `tuple_cast`, so there may be needless *copies* as well (the source type may not only contain pointers, or may contain some `unique_ptr`s already). I think you meant to `return tuple_cast<as_unique_t<Ts>...>(std::move(t));`. Also, I think `take_ownership` should only accept rvalues forcing a call to `std::move` at the callsite for lvalue source objects making it clear even to readers who don't know what `take_ownership` does that the source object is no longer usable after the call.

Comment: @casey good point.  On the other hand, `take_ownership` sort of implies it will take ownership from the input parameter.  Still, `std::move` tells the call site that the tuple/pair is no longer to be trusted, which is nice.

Comment: Two more issues: (1) `tuple`'s value constructors are explicit. (2) `pair` is not convertible from `tuple`. **[Fixed example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/aa08781c17c58eea)**.

Comment: @Casey I don't like having to pass the target "tuple" kind to `tuple_cast` -- http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/892480c54d5a3c80 is not perfect, but it avoids that.